# Retina screenshot (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, screenshot, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to take a screenshot of the UIView using the code below but it is creating a non-retina screenshot at half of the sizes of the actual device screen size.
Where am I going wrong?
Also `view.frame.size` is returning half of the actual values.

```
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, scale)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say `view.frame.size` is returning half the size, are you aware that it's sized in points?

Comment: Should I be getting the pixel value instead?

Comment: No; the pixel size will be `view.frame.size * scale`. Have you checked that `scale` is `2.0`?

Comment: Yes the scale is 2.0

Comment: This works for me just perfect for retina images.